# Java. Compare two objects values in LinkedList

Tags: java

```
public class Student {

public String name, surname;
int indexnr;

Student(String name, String surname, int indexnr) {
    this.name= name;
    this.surname= surname;
    this.indexnr= indexnr;

}
```

I have made two linked lists: list1 and list2 and both of lists contain 5 students. My mission is make third list - list3 which sort these students by index-numbers from lower to higher. Someone can help me please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? At least peruse the Java API (the `Collections` class should help you there)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: well.. Google and user3608003 can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add `implements Comparable<Student>` to class header and `compareTo()` method to `Student` class:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other) {
    return Integer.valueOf(this.indexnr).compareTo(other.indexnr);
}
```

Then, sort your list:

```
List<Student> list3 = ...; //some logic to fill list
Collections.sort(list3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If both Lists have the same size, you can iterate on one single loop.

Inside this loop, you should use any of these [Sorting Algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) by retrieving the indexnumbers of the students already in list3, and adding both student from list1 and list2 to their proper position.